# contour extraction

Tags: feature-extraction

Example: I as a user I have a database with 20 images but only 3 images obtain scene with sun. I would like to retrieve images from this database only with sun scene. I am using Fourier descriptor for discribing shape and I would like to obtain features vector from the image and this features vector compare and calculation Euclidian distance between real image and reference image database. BUT I would like to obtain features vector for reference sun image. I use segmentation and then I make converting image to binary format. I want to describe only object in image not background. How can I describe coutour image and obtain features vector?

Comment: Ideally, the image is divided into two parts foreground and background. The foreground object of interest (in my case, SUN) and background with others. How do I extract the feature vector only sun, not sun with the background?  or am I doing mistake? because my approach is that the image is segmented and then in each part of the segment will use Fourier shape descriptor and then I get a feature vector of each continuous  part, but I do not know which part segmented image have what a feature vectors, or know I?

Comment: My problem is that I dont know how can I isolated a features vectors every object in image with more object of interest

Answer (score 1):

What is the "background" here?

[image]

Now think ...

How did you decide?
Used colors?
Used size?
Used position?
Used some "sense of beauty"? ...

You can define the background only if you can tell some predicate about the foreground ... and that means *knowing* something about the object. That knowledge *perhaps* could be translated to code ...